# Date comparison in query: Correct logic but wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, time

I have this very simple query. But it's returning wrong result.

```
select * from `table_a` where date(`schedule`) > '2021-11-13 06:31:00'
```

In my table, I have these rows

```
table_a
+---------------------+
|      schedule       |
+---------------------+
| 2021-11-13 08:59:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2021-11-13 08:59:00 |
+---------------------+
| 2021-11-13 08:59:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Technically, this query should return all rows. But 0 rows is returned.
I tried changing the operation to `<`and it returned all rows (which is the opposite) . **Did I miss something here?**

note: `schedule` datatype is DATETIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `schedule` column is datetime, with a time component, so remove the cast to date:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE schedule > '2021-11-13 06:31:00';
```

What was happening is that your 3 records were all being casted to `2021-11-13` at midnight, which is the same as `2021-11-13 00:00:00`.  It should be clear that all of the 3 records occurred past midnight on this date.

Comment: Is this also applicable to the 'between' operation? I am using a laravel framework and it seemed that if I use the whereBetween() clause, it cast my passed parameter.

Comment: I can't help without seeing the Laravel code.